# locationServiceEnabled only allow iPhone 4?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-location, location-services

In the CoreLocation API, I am not sure why it is written as:

```
+ (BOOL)locationServicesEnabled __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_7,__IPHONE_4_0);
```

Notice that there's only Iphone 4 in the code. Does it mean it will only works for iphone 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means, that this feature is available **starting** from mac os 10.7 and iOS 4.0.